# react native textinput ref typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native

Whats the right type to use in my text input ref ?

It shows me error on line " <TextInput ref <-">

```
const RefComponent = () => {
  
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  return (
    <TextInput ref={inputRef} style={{height: 100, width: 500, backgroundColor: 'red', padding: 10}} />
  )
};
```

Error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: TextInputProps | Readonly<TextInputProps>): TextInput', gave the following error.
    Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<TextInput> | undefined'.
      Type 'MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement | null>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<TextInput>'.
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTMLInputElement works with web. For react-native, you can use following

```
const inputRef = useRef<typeof TextInput | null>(null);
```

Comment: For me it only works like this `const inputRef = useRef<TextInput | null>(null);` without the `typeof`

Comment: useRef<T> Here T represent type. TextInput is not an type.

Comment: That sounds logical though it did complain with `typeof` and without everything looked good ^^

Comment: More specifically `Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'typeof TextInput'.ts(2339)`